# ios: over release object in ARC

Tags: ios, nsautoreleasepool

I am using ARC in my project.

My application somtimes crash during deallocating a custom view. I think the object is already deallocated before, but autorelease pool try to deallocate it again.

What causes the problem is? I think I have not access view object in multi-threads.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00010012

0  CoreFoundation   CFRelease + 17
8  UIKit -[UIView dealloc] + 1420
9  mypreoject QuestionPage.m line 29 -[QuestionPage dealloc]
10 libobjc.A.dylib  (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 388
16 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 144
17 mypreoject   main.m line 13 main
18 libdyld.dylib start + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at QuestionPage.m line number twenty nine. Do you see anything fishy there?

Another suggestion would be to use Instruments to debug memory error, but I doubt there is any if you are using ARC.

What is also worthwhile is to go into your app's Build Settings and make sure ARC is actually used.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the code. The 29 line in QuestionPage.m is "}" after [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self].